# .ico not displayed in IE? is there any way I can show ico file in IE?

Tags: html, internet-explorer, ico

Code:

```
<img  src="../images/icons2/check.ico" alt=""/>
```

ico file is not diaplayed in IE.

is there any way I can show ico file in IE

Answer (score 3, accepted):

take a look at:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Comparison_of_web_browsers#Image_format_support those are all the image formats that a browser can support.

Convert your image to png, jpg or gif. There are even some online tools to do the job for you.
One example is: http://www.coolutils.com/online/image-converter/

Comment: so you are saying there is not way to use ico image in IE?

Comment: It's not a requirement for a web browser to support ico files (though some may support it). If you want cross browser compatibility you should avoid using .ico files inside img tags.