# Favicon is not showing in Internet Explorer

Tags: html, wordpress, favicon

Favicon is not showing on Internet Explorer

```
    <link rel="icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="favicon.ico" type="image/x-icon" />
```

I tried lots to showing Favicon on IE but failed can anyone know solution on that

Comment: i checked on IE8 and IE9 not working anywere

Comment: Working on FF Chorme safari

Comment: possible duplicate of [.ico not dislayed in IE? is there any way i can show ico file in IE?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6503096/ico-not-dislayed-in-ie-is-there-any-way-i-can-show-ico-file-in-ie)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I had the same problem in IE. In my case it was because the favicon.ico actually had a image/png content-type and not image/x-icon. Even when I created it with icon editors.

After converting a regular png file with http://www.convertico.com/ it worked.

Keep in mind though that IE caches this very strict. You might need to restart your browser and/or clear cache to see it.

Comment: Just an addition - instead of clearing the cache you can also rename the favicon file, or maybe even set the `href` value to `favicon.ico?nocache` :)